# out of memory exception trying to write a large array of data rows from the file to corda

Tags: java, corda

I need to write the sent data registry file to corda. I call the "call" method in"flow". The first lines are written normally.

When i try to write a large array of data rows in the corda occurs error:

```
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-default-fiber-pool"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-Same thread scheduler"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "rpc-server-reaper-0"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)"
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "server-timer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "threadDeathWatcher-3-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RxIoScheduler-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "MVStore background writer nio:C:/Users/Evsin/Desktop/CordaProjectV2/build/nodes/PartyA/persistence.mv.db"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "activemq-failure-check-thread"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-2 (activemq-netty-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-3 (activemq-netty-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-0 (activemq-netty-threads)"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)"
Exception in thread "Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Thread-2 (activemq-netty-threads)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

[Image with code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWKLk.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: And yes, maybe you are processing too much data. Try increasing the JVM heap size for starters.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most likely caused by an insufficient heap size. Corda nodes start with a Java heap size of 512MB by default.

You can increase the amount of Java heap memory available to the node by using the `-Xmx` command line argument when starting the node. For example, the following would run the node with a heap size of 2048MB:

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar corda.jar
```

Comment: in Intellij idea settings, the value is:
# custom options INTELLIJ idea VM

- Xms256m
- Xmx4096m
- XX: ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m

Comment: When you increase the heap size in IntelliJ, you're allocating additional heap space to the node driver, not the individual nodes.